# Remove outliers - Object cannot coerced to type 'double'

Tags: outliers

I want to remove outliers from my data (class: data.frame). This is my function code.

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm =  T)
y <- x
y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
y
}

data_withoutoutliers <- remove_outliers(data)
data_withoutoutliers <- remove_outliers(data[c(15:114,127:226,262:445)])
```

- However, when I apply my function to my data, there is an error message:

Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

- And when I apply the function only to the variables in which I want to omit the outliers (data[c(15:114,127:226,262:445)]), there is also an error message:

Error in quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE,  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Any help, please!